# How to access XML node containing a period using groovy.util.XmlParser

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing

I am needing to read a XML file where certain node names contain periods here is an example:

```
<build>
  <actions>
    <hudson.model.ParametersAction>
      <safeParameters class="sorted-set"/>
      <parameters>
        <hudson.model.StringParameterValue>
...
```

When I try to use the standard `build.actions.hudson.model.ParametersAction.parameters` I get

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Exception evaluating property 'hudson' for java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList, Reason: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: hudson for class: hudson.model.ParametersAction
```

I also tried `build.actions.'hudson.model.ParametersAction'.parameters` with this error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Exception evaluating property 'hudson.model.ParametersAction' for java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList, Reason: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: hudson.model.ParametersAction for class: hudson.model.ParametersAction
```

How can I access this property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that it's necessary to surround a "periodish" element with quotes. The below code works for me. If it still doesn't work for you, it will be better if you share the code snippet which instantiates `XmlParser` and parses the xml.

```
def xml = """
<build>
    <actions>
        <hudson.model.ParametersAction>
            <safeParameters class="sorted-set"/>
            <parameters>
                <hudson.model.StringParameterValue>foo</hudson.model.StringParameterValue>
            </parameters>
        </hudson.model.ParametersAction>
    </actions>
</build>
"""
def parser = new XmlParser()
def build = parser.parseText(xml)
println(build.actions.'hudson.model.ParametersAction'.parameters.'hudson.model.StringParameterValue'.text())
//prints foo as a result
```